# Not 'translating' string properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the following code, I have attempted to create a simple "translator" between a madeup language and English. If it worked properly, calling
`translate.toEnglish("hopeloplopo")` would return `hello`
Calling `translate.toLanguage("hello")` would return `hopeloplopo`

Basically, I want it to replace each non vowel with the letter+op, and vice versa in toEnglish

This is what currently happens:
`translate.toLanguage("hello")` returns 
`"OPello"`
`translate.toEnglish("hopeloplopo")` returns undefined

Please help, thanks!

```
var vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
var translate = {
    toEnglish:function(words) {
        function strip(text) {
            text = text.replace("OP", "").replace("op", "");
            if (text.toLowerCase().indexOf("op") >= 0) strip(text)
            else return text;
        }
        if (words.toLowerCase().indexOf("op") >= 0) strip(words)
        else return words;
    },
    toLanguage:function(words) {
        for (var i=0;i<words.length; i++) {
            if ($.inArray(words[i], vowels)<0) {
                var split = words.split(words[i]).join("OP");
                return split;
            }
            else {
                return words;
            }
        }
    },
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with your code? What doesn't it do? Give us something to work with, without having to produce our own examples. Show us some sample inputs and outputs.

Comment: By the way, when you translate `copulate` to your language and back, you get `culate`, see the problem?

Comment: `Please help, thanks!` - Help with what?  Is your code not working in some way?  What way would that be?  An error?  Unexpected output?  When you debug it, where and how does it fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't sure what your problem was so I just wrote how I'd do what you described

```
var translate = (function () {
    function toEnglish(str) {
        return str.replace(/(?=[a-z])([^aeiou])op/gi, '$1');
    }
    function toLanguage(str) {
        return str.replace(/(?=[a-z])([^aeiou])/gi, function ($0, $1) {
            return $1 + ($1 === $1.toUpperCase() ? 'OP' : 'op');
        });
    }
    return {
        toEnglish: toEnglish,
        toLanguage: toLanguage
    };
}());
```

Then

```
translate.toLanguage('Hello');      // "HOPeloplopo"
translate.toEnglish('HOPeloplopo'); // "Hello"
```